# Multiple consumers attached even after the application is closed. ActiveMQ

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, message-queue

I created a queue name "**CorConnectQAInvoiceTransmission**" queue, problem is that my queue is holding consumers even if the application is closed. As you can see in the image that currently 9 consumers are attached to the queue while all my application instances are closed.

[image]

Is there anyway that i could forcefully removed all the consumers from the queue without restarting broker as i might loss other messages? Also i am unable to understand even when the consumer is closed why it is still connected to the queue?

This is TCP connection URL which connecting to the broker:

```
activemq:tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0
```

Comment: What happens if you click the "Browse Active Consumers" link for that queue? Does it present you a way to disconnect the consumer?

Comment: No it only shows me the consumer with the status being active.

Comment: Are you closing your JMS connection, session and consumer explicitly in the application code?